# Axios PUT got Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, axios

I have axios PUT method in API and it's got Unhandled Runtime Error

[Here's Image of an Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suMqY.png)

Error: Request failed with status code 500

```
update: async (article, pid, token) => {
        const { data, status } = await axios.put(
          `${apiPath}/articles/${pid}`,
          JSON.stringify({ article }),
          {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Token ${encodeURIComponent(token)}`,
            },
          }
        )
        return {
          data,
          status,
        }
      },
```

But for POST method it working real fine, so I'm in very deep confusion

```
create: async (article, token) => {
    const { data, status } = await axios.post(
      `${apiPath}/articles`,
      JSON.stringify({ article }),
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Token ${encodeURIComponent(token)}`,
        },
      }
    )
    return {
      data,
      status,
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: a 500 is a server error. Do you have the log from the server with the error message in it?